# How can I create a chrome extension that opens diffrent google tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a chrome extension that act like this one: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/create-google-docs/mgealjdnniclkdecdodfiinjgjifjbfo
(code for the script will be below)

However I want to change the urls from https://docs.google.com/document/create that to : https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/create

The thing I could do is just copy and paste and upload it to the Chrome store, but thats copy righted.

Lastly I have no clue how to code. I have tried but yea.

```
function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
  console.log(info.menuItemId + ' clicked.')
  // メニューが選択された時の処理
  if (info.menuItemId == "document_id") {
    window.open('https://docs.google.com/document/create');
  }else if (info.menuItemId == "spreadsheet_id") {
    window.open('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/create');
  }else if (info.menuItemId == "presentation_id") {
    window.open('https://docs.google.com/presentation/create');
  }else if (info.menuItemId == "form_id") {
    window.open('https://docs.google.com/forms/create');
  }else if (info.menuItemId == "drawing_id") {
    window.open('https://docs.google.com/drawings/create');
  }else if (info.menuItemId == "script_id") {
    window.open('https://script.google.com/macros/create');
  }else if (info.menuItemId == "mydrive_id") {
    window.open('https://drive.google.com/');
  }
};

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {

  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Document",
    "id": "document_id",
  });
  console.log("New Document created.");

  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Spreadsheet",
    "id": "spreadsheet_id",
  });
  console.log("New Spreadsheet created.");

  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Presentation",
    "id": "presentation_id",
  });
  console.log("New Presentation created.");

    chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Form",
    "id": "form_id",
  });
  console.log("New Form created.");

    chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Drawing",
    "id": "drawing_id",
  });
  console.log("New Spreadsheet created.");

    chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Script",
    "id": "script_id",
  });
  console.log("New Script created.");

  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "My Drive",
    "id": "mydrive_id",
  });
  console.log("My Drive.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing the same thing a little bit more easy to understand

we need a background script to handle the context menu, and the functions in it. And a popup.html.

First i specify a script called "myscripts.js" running in the background, on manifest.json

**manifest.json**

```js
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "New Docs",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "",
"browser_action":
 {
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
 },
"background": {
    "scripts": ["myscripts.js"]
},  
"permissions": [
    "contextMenus"
]}
```

Then i create the context menus and add a function to each one, that is triggered whenever you click on them

**myscript.js**

```js
///////////////////////// Functions /////////////////////////

function child1click() {
  chrome.tabs.create({  
    url: "https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/create",
  });           
}
function child2click() {
  chrome.tabs.create({  
    url: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/create",
  });           
}
function child3click() {
  chrome.tabs.create({  
    url: "https://docs.google.com/presentation/u/0/create",
  });           
}
function child4click() {
  chrome.tabs.create({  
    url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0create",
  });           
}
function child5click() {
  chrome.tabs.create({  
    url: "https://docs.google.com/drawings/u/0/create",
  });           
}
function child6click() {
  chrome.tabs.create({  
    url: "https://script.google.com/macros/u/0/create",
  });           
}
function child7click() {
  chrome.tabs.create({  
    url: "https://drive.google.com/",
  });           
}

///////////////////////// Context Menus /////////////////////////

///// Parent contextMenu /////

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Create New Docs",
    contexts: ["all"],
    id: "parent",
});

/////  Sub Context Menu /////

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Document",
    contexts:["all"],
    parentId: "parent",
    id: "child1",
    onclick: child1click,
});
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "SpreadSheet",
    contexts:["all"],
    parentId: "parent",
    id: "child2",
    onclick: child2click,   
});
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Presentation",
    contexts:["all"],
    parentId: "parent",
    id: "child3",
    onclick: child3click,
});
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Form",
    contexts:["all"],
    parentId: "parent",
    id: "child4",
    onclick: child4click,
});
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Drawing",
    contexts:["all"],
    parentId: "parent",
    id: "child5",
    onclick: child5click,
});
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Script",
    contexts:["all"],
    parentId: "parent",
    id: "child6",
    onclick: child6click,
});
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "My Drive",
    contexts:["all"],
    parentId: "parent",
    id: "child7",
    onclick: child7click,
});
```

**popup.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Create Google Docs</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/create" target="_blank" title="Create new Document"><img src="img/dc.png"></a>
<a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u//0create" target="_blank" title="Create new Spreadsheet"><img src="img/ss.png"></a>
<a href="https://docs.google.com/presentation/u/0/create" target="_blank" title="Create new Presentation"><img src="img/pt.png"></a>
<a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/create" target="_blank" title="Create new Form"><img src="img/fo.png"></a>
<a href="https://docs.google.com/drawings/u/0/create" target="_blank" title="Create new Drawing"><img src="img/dw.png"></a>
<a href="https://script.google.com/macros/u/0/create" target="_blank" title="Create new Script"><img src="img/sc.png"></a>
<a href="https://drive.google.com/" target="_blank" title="Go to Google Drive"><img src="img/drive.png"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```css
body {
    min-width: 30px;
}

a {
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    /*text-align: center;*/
    -webkit-transition: all 0s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0s ease;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    background: #D3D3D3;
}

.text{
    color: Black;
    font-size: 12px;
}

img {
    margin-top: -5px;

}
```

as you can see, in popup.html there use some images that are in a folder, to get that images you right click the "Create google docs" extension, and you select "inspect popup", then go to "sources" and then "network" and there you have the popup files from the extension, so you go to the folder img, and downloand all the images into a img folder on your extension folder... it should look something like this
[image: a image of my extension folder with all the files on it]

Here is a link to all the images if you want to downloand them all in just one click https://mega.nz/#!4vpFyKpY!IErDgvi4kR2L6D2XactUEOQoiQIFYyoqoJPWPX7J4OM

Comment: Thank you holyTrap, however when I click on the extension now it shows the menu (like if your right clicking).  https://imgur.com/a/DTEjc

Comment: Now with that if I put it into: https://jsfiddle.net/jonathen/yht729z5/   It works but when I put it in my folder it wont. When i click my extension it just shows the code.  https://imgur.com/a/AAkeZ

Comment: when you click in the icon, the file that its displayed is popup.html, what i give you its the context menu and their functions... if you load the files i give you into a new extension and you right click the screen, it will show up exactly like its in the original extension.